# Bootstrap multiselect dropdown checkbox not working on paginated table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, datatables, bootstrap-multiselect

I am having a dynamically populated paginated table. I am using "bootstrap multiselect checkbox " option in one of the column. This plugin works fine in first page of the table , but when i try to navigate to next pages on paginated table , "boostrap multiselect drop down checkbox options become a plain normal multiselect option without checkbox. Also search option is not working .Is there something missing here ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/searchDataTable.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.applicationNameSelectClass').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption : true ,
             enableFiltering: true,
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dbResultsTable').dataTable();
} );
</script>

                <form id="form">
                    <table border="1" id="dbResultsTable" class="table table-striped" >
                        <!-- Dynamically populated table  -->
                    </table>
                <input type="submit" id="submitId"/>
                  </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your dynamically populated table, You can hook an event handler to datatable [page change event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page) (datatable version >= 1.10) and there re-init the multiselect dropdown inside that.

```
$('#dbResultsTable').on( 'page.dt', function () {

$('.applicationNameSelectClass').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption : true ,
             enableFiltering: true,
        });
});
```

Edit:

Here is [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7x6vc4vc/12/)

Changed the page.dt to draw.dt, as page.dt is firing too early.

```
    $('#dbResultsTable').on('draw.dt', function () {

       $('.applicationNameSelectClass').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption : true ,
             enableFiltering: true,
        });
});
```

Comment: its not working , after using this code multiselect dropdown   option is not working in any page :(

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a jsfiddle example? Which version of datatable are you using? Is page.dt event firing? The datatable must be initialized before you attach the page.dt event handler.

Comment: I am using DataTables-1.10.4 version. page.dt event is not getting triggered i am initializing datatables before attaching page.dt event handler. i will try to create jsfiddle example for you.

Comment: ..here is jsfiddle link :- http://jsfiddle.net/7x6vc4vc/1/  but i couldn't find bootstrap multiple select cdn link so it wont give idea about my problem . please give a thought on this

Comment: Updated answer and your fiddle also.

Comment: thanks a million :)  i was struggling with this for quite some time. just one more thing , why my search option is not working ?

Comment: In the example jsfiddle search works just ok for me.

Comment: yes because in example i gave static data , for me it works for static data but not for dynamically populated data

Comment: I have no clear idea about that here http://jsfiddle.net/euryqcrf/31/ the data is from json source and search works just fine. Make sure there is no syntax error in javascript console.